# Alguien conoce una herramienta open source o de pago que soporte git y ftp

Tags: git, gitlab, ftpclient

Quisiera saber si hay una herramienta de gestión de proyectos open source o de pago, en la que poder hacer todo en uno, tipo manejar diversos proyectos con to dos y esas cosas, que soporte git, acceso a servidores ftp, cliente de bases de datos, etc, de última mi pregunta sería si es posible empezar un proyecto open source para tener una herramienta así.

Comment: Las preguntas basadas en opiniones terminan cerradas, por favor lee [ask]

Answer (score -4, accepted):

AzureDevops creo que sería una herramienta ideal para lo que estás buscando. Puedes buscar más información de la misma en la web.

> DevOps es la unión de personas, procesos y tecnologías para permitir
>   la entrega continua de valor a los clientes. DevOps incluye prácticas
>   principales, como planeamiento y seguimiento, desarrollo, compilación
>   y pruebas, entrega, supervisión y operaciones. Estas prácticas, junto
>   con las herramientas y tecnologías de DevOps, permiten automatizar el
>   ciclo de vida de las aplicaciones.
>
> https://martincarlsen.com/ftp-deploy-from-vsts/

Comment: Dale, muchas gracias, pero es posible trabajar en un entorno de c++ y web al mismo tiempo?

Comment: La idea del programa es que puedas tener un mejor seguimiento de tu proyecto y lo que está ocurriendo en tiempo real, ya de los lenguajes a utilizar depende de tu proyecto y el alcanze que le des vos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, un saludo grande